# Linked List does not iterate in while loop correctly when using next method

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, reverse

I am trying to reverse a linked list iteratively using a stack. I have identified where the problem is occurring, but for the life of me, can't figure out why the code isn't iterating correctly when I call the next method of a ListNode. I have marked in the code below, where the bug occurs.

This is the result when I run the code:

```
Before: 1->2->3->4->null
After: 4->3->3->4->null
```

This is what the result should be:

```
Before: 1->2->3->4->null
After: 4->3->2->1->null
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction as to what is going on? Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        private static Solution soln = new Solution();
        ListNode head = makeLinkedList(4);

        System.out.print("Before: ");
        printLinkedList(head);
        System.out.println();

        soln.reverseList(head);

        System.out.print(" After: ");
        printLinkedList(head);

        System.exit(0);
    }

    public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
        Stack<ListNode> listContents = new Stack<ListNode>();

        // iterate list and add to stack
        ListNode tmp = head;
        while (tmp != null) {
            listContents.push(tmp);
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }

        // iterate list again and replace each val with stack val
        tmp = head;
        while (tmp != null) {
            tmp.val = listContents.pop().val;
            // this is where the code seems to fail
            tmp = tmp.next; 
        }
        return head;
    }
}
```

How the ListNode is defined:

```
public class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next = null;

    public ListNode(int item) { 
        val = item; 
    }
}
```

Here is how I create a linked list:

```
private static ListNode makeLinkedList(int numNodes) {
    ListNode head = null;
    ListNode tmp = null;
    for (int i = 1; i < numNodes + 1; i++) {
        if (tmp == null) {
            tmp = new ListNode(i);
            head = tmp;
        } else {
            tmp.next = new ListNode(i);
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

A helper method:

```
private static void printLinkedList(ListNode head) {
    ListNode tmp = head;
    while (tmp != null) {
        System.out.print(tmp.val + "->");
        tmp = tmp.next;
    }
    System.out.print("null");
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code where `next` gets set.  (It would be even more helpful to have a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.)

Comment: Yes, we certainly can't tell what's going on from just these snippets.

Comment: Well, if Jon Skeet can't tell what's going on, I can stop wasting my time here...

Comment: scmosel, I believe in you!

Comment: I have added a more Complete set of code as it pertains to the problem! :-)

Comment: `Push` and `pop` in particular would be helpful to see, IMO (although MCV is still best.)

Comment: shmosel always have a great sense of humor. :))

Comment: @D M, what does MCV stand for? :)

Comment: @D M, also I have used the built in Stack imported from "java.util.Stack;"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @D M, ahhhh i see, cool! Thanks!

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm afraid I've found the answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that was the built-in Stack and got confused - after your edits this was indeed a MCVE.  (Except for that first line in main which wouldn't let it compile.)  By the time I figured out the problem, someone else already had.

Comment: Np, D M, your input is still very welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why does it not work?

The problem is you're storing the `ListNode`s in the `Stack` instead of just the values. This way, you're overwriting the values of the nodes you're then reading:

- You start with stack (top first): 4 - 3 - 2 - 1
- You take former head, pop stack, and write the value

  - New list: 4
  - Stack however now is: 3 - 2 - **4** (you overwrote value in head)
- Next element

  - New list: 4 - 3
  - Stack: **3** - 4 (you overwrote value in second list node)
- Next element

  - New list: 4 - 3 - 3
  - Stack: 4
- Last element

  - New list: 4 - 3 - 3 - 4

#### What to do to make it work?

Several possible ways to fix it:

- Only store the values in the stack.
- Create new `ListNode`s for the reversed list.
- Reconnect the nodes instead of rewriting their values. Note that this can be done without even using the `Stack` - see how in @xenteros' answer.

Comment: But why wouldn't this work? (Obviously the alt. sol'n would work)

Comment: @A.Pahlavan Because right in the first iteration of second loop you write `4` into the former head node, then when you get to the new tail, you pop the former head node from stack and it does indeed now have the value of `4`.

Comment: So he doesn't necessarily need to push only the values on the stack!

Comment: @A.Pahlavan If you only push the *values* on the stack, you won't modify what's on the stack when you change the value of any `ListNode`.

Comment: @JiriTousek, ahh that makes sense, thx! care to elaborate on how this can be done w/o a stack?

Comment: @moped You can see a solution without the stack in my answer.

Comment: See xenteros' answer for no-stack solution

Comment: What if you need other members of that node, than you'd need to push the node on the stack and so this wouldn't be a general solution. In other words, this solution is correct, but wouldn't be sufficient in all cases.

Comment: @A.Pahlavan that's true, however the general pattern is for a "list" to only have one data item, the "payload" - which itself may hold more attributes. See e.g. `LinkedList<T>` - each node only has one item of type `<T>`. But I agree that reconnecting the nodes is a better approach than moving the values around. Take my answer as an analyses of *why does it not work* rather than *how to do it properly*.

Answer (score 2):

Reversing a linked list should be done by reversing links if possible. I'd try the following:

```
public static ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
    // iterate list and add to stack
    ListNode current = head;
    ListNode previous = null;
    ListNode temp = null;
    while (current.next != null) {
        temp = previous;
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
        previous.next = temp;
    }
    current.next = previous;
    return current;
}
```

It returns a new head. Example usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ListNode head = makeLinkedList(4);

    System.out.print("Before: ");
    printLinkedList(head);
    System.out.println();

    head = reverseList(head);

    System.out.print(" After: ");
    printLinkedList(head);

    System.exit(0);
}

>>Before: 1->2->3->4->null
>>After: 4->3->2->1->null
>>Process finished with exit code 0
```

The algorithm description would be:
For each node in a list, instead of linking next element, link the previous one and return the last element as head.

Comment: wow this looks like a great answer, however, I forgot to mention the contraint to the problem was that it needed to be singly linked list. Regardless, thanks for your valuable input!

Comment: @moped it is singly linked list! I just change the direction of the arrows.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are mutating your LinkedList without being aware of it. In other words, when you overwrite the value of any more in your LinkedList, the nodes that you've pushed on the stack previously would also get modified. Therefore, one way ensure this would not happen is to instantiate and push a new node (copy) on the stack:

```
public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
 Stack<ListNode> listContents = new Stack<ListNode>();

 // iterate list and add to stack
 ListNode tmp = head;

 while (tmp != null) {
     ListNode newNode = new ListNode(temp);
     listContents.push(newNode);
     tmp = tmp.next;
 }

 // iterate list again and replace each val with stack val
 tmp = head;
 while (tmp != null) {
     tmp.val = listContents.pop().val;
     tmp = tmp.next; 
 }
 return head;
}
```

Simple modification to the `ListNode` class to add copy constructor:

```
public class ListNode {
  int val;
  ListNode next = null;

  public ListNode (ListNode that){
     this.val = that.val;
      this.next = null;     //Could be that.next
   }

  public ListNode(int item) { 
      val = item; 
  }
}
```